# White screen after splash screen,Ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic2

there is white screen keep showing for a long time after splash screen.I also uninstalled and installed typescript and updated my packgae.json and also updated node module by npm install.But no help till now.Can anyone provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this two line in config.xml

```
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
 <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="800" />
```

now run the command

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

i hope your white space problem is resolved